# Get data from url .txt with function

Tags: php

when i use this function `function get_data($url)` all my content website disappear, I tried with `function get_web_page( $url )` , but is not working..

With this function I want see the content from: `http://swapes.com/version.txt` in another site..

what can use if `function get_data($url)` not working?

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header = array(
                "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*\/*;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Keep-Alive: 300",
                "Pragma: ");
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(!empty($data)){
        return $data;
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}

    // Get Latest Version
    include_once("../version.php");
    $l_version = get_data('http://swapes.com/version.txt');
```

this is the code php from footer.php, where when i add the "get_data" code disappear the footer.

```
 <?
include_once("test1.php");

?>

<div  class='logged' id="under-content">
<div id="sub-content-box">

</table></div>
<div id="sub-content-box">
<table id="nested" width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Ethics</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                </table>
<b>It is important to remember that is a community. We are all here for the same reason and we should help eachother.</b></th><br>

<li><U>Don't Aggressively Unfollow/Unlike</U></li>
<li><U>Don't Spam Profiles/Pages</U></li>
<li><U>Don't Create Multiple Accounts</U></li>
<li><U>Don't Use Bots/Macros/Scripts</U></li>
<li><U>Don't Buy or Sell Accounts</U></li>

<b>Anyone found to be breaking any of this will be removed from this site permanently.</b></div>

<div id="sub-content-box">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:32px;text-align:center;line-height: 11px;" id="tour"></br>Updates</a>
<div style="background: #FFF6BF;color: #514721;border-color: #FFD324;padding: 5px 10px;margin: 0 0 5px;border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;"><h6>16/05/2011 15:00</h6>New update is available for comments plugin! <br/><a href="javascript: void(0)">Update now</a></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" style="width:208px;height:102px;text-align:center;line-height: 21px;" id="tour"></br>
<div style="font-size:11px;margin:3px 15px"><b>Your Version:</b> <?=($config['version'] < $l_version ? '<strong style="color:red">'.$config['version'].'</strong></a>' : '<strong style="color:green">'.$config['version'].'</strong>')?></span></div>
<div style="font-size:11px;margin:2px 15px"><b>Latest Version:</b> <strong style="color:blue"><?=(!empty($l_version) ? $l_version : $config['version'])?></strong></span></div>
</a>
</div>


    </div><?php  if (ae_detect_ie()) {  ?></td></tr></table><?php } ?>
    <div id="sub-content">
    <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/after-login.php?what=politcy&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'politcy';">Privacy Politcy</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/after-login.php?what=contact&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'contact';">Contact Us</a> <a href="">

    </a><a href="#" style="float:right">Swapes.com - All rights reserved (c) 2014 </a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"but is not working"_ isn't sufficient description of the problem. Be specific

Comment: Is `get_web_page` & `get_data` functions created by you ? Can you post the code of that function ?

Comment: I tried `please_finish_my_whole_website_based_on_my_assumed_requirements($data)`, but it didn't work either. Maybe that's not how scripting works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `echo` statement to print your data that is returned by your function.

```
// Get Latest Version
include_once("../version.php");
echo $l_version = get_data('http://swapes.com/version.txt'); //<--- Add `echo` as shown.
```

#### Modified Code

```
<?php

function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header = array(
        "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*\/*;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Keep-Alive: 300",
        "Pragma: ");
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(!empty($data)){
        return $data;
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}

// Get Latest Version
include_once("../version.php");
echo $l_version = get_data('http://swapes.com/version.txt');
```

Comment: nothing... all content from my site disappear when add this function

Comment: `echo` is not a _function_. You are calling `get_data` with some url and it is returning data.. but you are not displaying it anywhere. Adding the `echo` shows , output as **2.0** . I have tested your code personally and it works.

Comment: if all disappear, you may be need to set php.ini to show error.

Comment: I added, but instead to see 2.0 , all my website content disappear... I have this code and in another site and is working, but in this site is not working

Comment: can be an problem if this page were i tried to add is an jquery page
?

Comment: That is definitely a PHP misconfiguration issue. Create a simple test file named `test.php` and add this code and check out `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: Can you copy the exact code what I pasted on the answer and create a `test1.php` and try out ? See the **modified answer**

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran swapes.com/cPanel/test.php seems all ok no?

Comment: yes is working, but when i add in footer.php the footer is disappear... why? :(

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran , i added and the footer.php code

Comment: Can you link the page if possible ?

Comment: swapes.com , but need login: user: koskos , pass: 15051991